# Using glBindVertexArray(0) on JOGL with swing results in black screen

Tags: java, swing, opengl, jogl

So I'm writing a JOGL app with Swing GUI using a JGLPanel. The code is as follows,

```
public class GLWindow implements GLEventListener {

(...)

public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    gl.glClear(GL4.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glFlush();
}

public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gl = arg0.getGL().getGL4();

    glu = new JGLU();

    // clear color
    gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.3f, 0.2f, 1.0f);


    gl.glBindVertexArray(0);

}

public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3,
        int arg4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL4));
    gljpanel = new GLJPanel(caps);

    GLWindow window = new GLWindow();

    gljpanel.addGLEventListener(window);


}
```

(The code for GUI setup is omitted.)

Whem I run this, I get a black screne. When I remove the line with gl.glBindVertexArray(0); the program program runs fine, and I get a a reddish screen. When I try to render a model using a VAO, it only renders if I don't unbind the VAO. Anyone knows why???

EDIT: Actually, what is going on is that the 'display' method is only being called when  the window starts or whent it's resized. Anyone knows a workaround?

Comment: Where is `init` called?

Comment: Ah, sorry, init is a method in the Class window, so it gets called because of gljpanel.addGLEventListener(window);

Comment: "When I try to render a model using a VAO..." could you show me where in this code you try to render using a VAO? The only VAO-related line I can see is the `gl.glBindVertexArray(0);` line you mentioned as causing problems.

Comment: I could, but it's a really long code. But when I do something like glBindVertexArray(vao); glDrawArrays(...); glBindVertexArray(0); it only renders if I remove glBindVertexArray(0); Else I get a black screen.

Comment: I've done a lot of other programs in JOGL, but this is the first time I use it with a swing interface. Never had this problem before.

Comment: I'm thinking about removing all glBindVertexArray(0), but it kind of annoys me not knowing why this is hapenning.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, sorry. I've never had that problem in my own programs, but I haven't used JOGL (I've used LWJGL and the native C interface). Good luck!

Comment: I haven't use JOGL, but basically when using VAO, the step is:  bind VAO-- set attributes---  in game loop draw stuff and process other event( bind VAO--> render stuff-> unbind VAO) . Please check your steps and see if the display method correctly bind to GUI event system.

Comment: What about creating your VAO first?

Comment: Hi Daniel, have you solved?

Comment: Hey, I have the exact same problem and can't find a solution anywhere... Have you managed to solve it?